# Developing asp.net core applications on Linux, using VSCode shows wrong/misleading build errors

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I'm experiencing lot of problems developing asp.net core applications on Linux, using VSCode. When trying to build application it shows wrong errors like `Entity not found` or `error CS1501 : no Overload for Method takes 2 arguments` but the entity is there or the method do accept 2 arguments. When trying to restart VSCode, it still show the wrong error. The error is only shown on Terminal when trying to build the application.

Like the following error:
`bookshop/Areas/admin/BookController.cd{97,55): error CS1501 : no Overload for Method 'AddBookAsync' takes 2 arguments [path/BookShop/BookShop.csproj]`

BookController looks like this :
[image: BookController.cs]

And the BookService looks like this:
[image: BookService.cs]

Even VSCode doesn't detect any error but when building the app using dotnet cli, the error pops up & prevents the app from completing the build. I've tried removing vscode & dotnet caches on system but it doesn't solve the problem.